# pfSense traffic shaping with CBQ

Tags: pfsense

I'm new to networking, but I did some research, and I could not determine the source of the problem.

I want to prioritize gaming traffic by port, destination, or anything else I decide.

I configured the pfSense box to prioritize gaming traffic by destination, using rules on the LAN interface to put the gaming traffic in a qGame queue on tier 5.

Then, I tried to play, and everything was OK. I then opened some YouTube videos, and the games were not lagging, but when I opened another 25 computers on the network, the game started lagging.

Game traffic was going to the qGame queue, and I observed it was small traffic, as I expected, and any other traffic was going to the qLink and qDefault traffic queues.

So, I performed another experiment. I put a PC with torrent download on the network, and I put its IP address in a LAN rule to send its traffic to the qp2p queue. The torrent PC traffic was indeed going to the qp2p traffic queue that has a priority of 1, and the qDefault queue with a priority of 3. With that unspecified traffic, I started a YouTube video, and I pinged a DNS server to see the latency. The ping was a normal 200-400 ms with YouTube videos and low torrent traffic. After a minute, the ping got high, and the video was stopping, and I started to lose ping traffic.

Torrent traffic that was going to the qp2p queue with a priority of 1 was taking more bandwidth than the qDefault that has a priority of 3.

I stopped the torrent PC to use the Internet and for other reasons.

```
pfTop: Up Queue 1-16/16, View: queue
QUEUE               BW SCH  PR  PKTS BYTES DROP_P DROP_B QLEN BORR SUSP P/S            B/S
root_em0         1000K cbq   0  9784  953K      0      0    0    0    0         
qInternet       1000K cbq         0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qACK            190K cbq   6     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qDefault       90000 cbq   3  9784  953K      0      0    0 3997    0         
qP2P           40000 cbq         0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qGames          190K cbq   5     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qOthersHigh    90000 cbq   4     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qOthersLow     50000 cbq   2     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
root_em1          100M cbq   0 18568   21M      0      0    0    0    0         
qLink             20M cbq   2 18568   21M      0      0    0  703    0         
qInternet       4096K cbq         0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qACK            778K cbq   6     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qP2P            163K cbq         0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qGames          778K cbq   5     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qOthersHigh     368K cbq   4     0     0      0      0    0    0    0         
qOthersLow      204K cbq   3     0     0      0      0    0    0    0
```

Why is a lower priority queue taking more bandwidth that a high priority queue? Do borrow options override the priority with the CBQ scheduler?

Is there a way for the qP2P queue to take only that extra traffic without causing the qDefault queue traffic to lag?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. From the [help]: "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._"

Comment: i'm doing this for a cyber cafe with more then 30 PC

Comment: if i want to manage an enterprise network i need to start with small networks please i need some help here

Comment: Then you should provide more information. A network diagram would be helpful, along with the network devices, models, and configurations. Understand that QoS should be a comprehensive, network-wide solution. QoS is only valid on your network; you cannot control what is coming to you from outside, (the incoming bandwidth usage), only what is already on, or leaving, your network. Also, no carriers on the Internet, except maybe your own ISP (if you pay for it), will honor your QoS policies and markings, and your traffic will pass through multiple carriers on the way to its destination(s).

Comment: thanks man i think i got it  i will answer my question to show how i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

router can control traffic that is going to the internet only and can't control income traffic

router can control income traffic only if its tcp packets. tcp traffic have  congestion control .so the receiver can control how much traffic he want from the sender

there is udp packets that can't be controlled by local router it need a isp router so isp router can take all the income traffic from the internet and decide which packets need to be deliver and which should be delayed or dropped